# Как найти площадь пересечения окружностей?

Tags: c, алгоритм, геометрия

Нужно найти площадь пересечения двух окружностей (формулы взял [тут](http://www.abakbot.ru/online-2/73-ploshhad-peresecheniya-okruzhnostej)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*S* = *S*<sub>1</sub> + *S*<sub>2</sub>

где,

- *R*<sub>1</sub> — радиус первой окружности;
- *R*<sub>2</sub> — радиус второй окружности;
- *D* — расстояние между центрами окружностей.

Код:

```
float find_area(float x1, float y1, float r1, float x2, float y2, float r2) {

    // Расстояние между центрами окружностей
    float distance = sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)); 
    float f1, f2;
    float s1, s2;
    if(distance >= r1 + r2) {
        // Если не пересекаются (можно дополнить вычислением площади внутренней окружности)
        return 0;
    }else if(distance <= fabs(r1 - r2)) {
        // Если окружность внутри другой
        return 0;            
    }
    else {
        // Если пересекаются
        f1 = 2 * acos((r1*r1 - r2*r2 - distance*distance) / (2 * r1 * distance));
        f2 = 2 * acos((r2*r2 - r1*r1 - distance*distance) / (2 * r2 * distance));
        s1 = (r1*r1 * (f1 - sin(f1))) / 2;
        s2 = (r2*r2 * (f2 - sin(f2))) / 2;

        return s1 + s2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Площадь пересечения окружностей

(x<sub>1</sub> = 0; y<sub>1</sub> = 0; r<sub>1</sub> = 2) ∩ (x<sub>2</sub> = 3; y<sub>2</sub> = 0; r<sub>2</sub> = 4)

должна быть равна примерно 9.57019, но у меня выводит что-то непонятное:

> -1.#IND00

Comment: `+D^2`, а у вас минус.

Comment: Да, все работает, спасибо.

Comment: Рекомендую использовать `double` вместо `float` в подобных расчётах, если нет специальных ограничений на этот счёт.

Comment: Ещё: если одна окружность внутри другой, то их площадь пересечения равна площади меньшей из них.

Comment: @Zealint, Это будет работать только для кругов, если один круг внутри другого, то площадь пересечения == площади меньшего из них. Или для окружностей также ?

Comment: Так, погодите. Сначала я подумал, что вы используете слово окружность в обыденном смысле, а не в математическом. В математическом смысле любая окружность имеет нулевую площадь (это тонкая линия), поэтому любое пересечение с чем угодно при любом раскладе будет иметь нулевую площадь. Так что даже формулы не нужны. А я дал комментарий именно для слова "круг".

Comment: Справедливости ради, "пересечение окружностей" может иметь площадь.Им не нужно быть кругами, чтобы выделить участок на плоскости.

Comment: @vp_arth: С теоретико-множественной точки зрения _пересечение_ двух множеств есть _подмножество_ любого из них. Так что пересечение окружностей в типичном случае — две точки, а не ограниченный участок.

Comment: @vp_arth, окружность представляется спрямляемой кривой, что говорит о возможности найти длину, но не площадь. Вы же рассказываете о совершенно другом, а именно об интегрировании участков, образованных двумя функциями на плоскости.

Answer (score 1):

В комментариях уже всё обсудили, добавлю только что неплохо было бы проверить аргументы `acos` на `[-1...1]`, а то знаете ли, бывают такие окружности, что круг в них не помещается :-) В смысле, что формула строго не доказана на всём диапазоне значений. Кстати, спасибо автору за код! :-)

Comment: Очевидно же, что расстояние между кругами должно быть меньше или равно сумме радиусов, иначе просто пересечения не будет. И там выше есть проверка

Answer (score 1):

В коде ошибка!

```
acos((r1*r1 - r2*r2 - distance*distance)
```

Исходя из формулы, квадрат дистанции надо прибавлять

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript реализация на основе формулы из [нажми](https://abakbot.ru/online-2/73-ploshhad-peresecheniya-okruzhnostej).

```
function Circle(x, y , r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;

    this.getAreaOfCircle = function() {
        let areaOfCircle = Math.PI * Math.pow(this.r, 2);
        return areaOfCircle;
    }
}

const firstСircle = new Circle(0, 0, 3);
const secondCircle = new Circle(5, 0, 4);

function getAreaOfIntersectionOfCircles(firstСircle, secondCircle) {
    let distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((firstСircle.x - secondCircle.x), 2) + Math.pow((firstСircle.y - secondCircle.y), 2));

    if (distance >= firstСircle.r + secondCircle.r) {
        return 0;
    } else if ((distance + secondCircle.r) <= firstСircle.r) {
        return secondCircle.getAreaOfCircle()
    } else if ((distance + firstСircle.r) <= secondCircle.r) {
        return firstСircle.getAreaOfCircle()
    } else {
        const F1 = 2 * Math.acos(((firstСircle.r * firstСircle.r) - (secondCircle.r * secondCircle.r) + (distance * distance)) / (2 * firstСircle.r * distance));
        const F2 = 2 * Math.acos(((secondCircle.r * secondCircle.r) - (firstСircle.r * firstСircle.r) + (distance * distance)) / (2 * secondCircle.r * distance));

        const S1 = ((firstСircle.r * firstСircle.r) * (F1 - Math.sin(F1))) / 2;
        const S2 = ((secondCircle.r * secondCircle.r) * (F2 - Math.sin(F2))) / 2;

        return S1 + S2;
    }
}

console.log(`Area of intersection of circles: ${getAreaOfIntersectionOfCircles(firstСircle, secondCircle).toFixed(2)}`);
```